# ad vs offer vs announcement -- selling and renting

Tags: vocabulary

ad vs offer vs announcement -- selling and renting

We can say to a landlord:

*I saw your rental ad on facebook and I'm interested.*

But I think we can't say the following to a friend:

*I saw your shoes ad on facebook and I want them*

Should we go for something like "shoes offer/announcement" (this friend wants to sell her shoes)?

I think we can go for something simple:
*I saw you put your shoes for sale on Fb*

but I would like to know words such as *ad, offer* or maybe also *announcement* have their place in these contexts, this is, renting and selling (commercially, non-commercially, on Facebook, etc.

Comment: You're mistaken in thinking that ***rental ad*** is a valid collocation, but ***shoes ad*** isn't. You've probably seen the first one more often, but they're both just casual / sloppy usages, of equal status syntactically speaking.

Comment: It depends exactly what is being posted. If someone puts as their facebook status "I think I'll sell my shoes", that's probably not an ad, although you might message them and say "I saw your facebook status and if you're selling your shoes I might be interested". If they put up something saying "shoes for sale, $20", that is an ad. It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

As FumbleFingers says, both are either valid or invalid depending on the usage. They are fine if used in s "casual / sloppy" way but in a more formal environment you might say

> I'm interested in the rental advertisement you placed on Facebook.
> or
> I would like to buy the shoes you advertised on FB.

However there are differences between ad, offer and announcement.
**ad** (casual for advert or advertisement) is a statement that a particular item or service is available, bringing it to the attention of interested parties.
An advertisement may well include an **offer** to sell at a specific price, but you could also **offer** your friend a lower price for their shoes. Note offer also hase other uses such as to **offer help**.
Advertisements are **announcements** that something is available for sale, but there is a wider usage - you can, for example, announce a wedding or any other piece of information you / a company / the government believe of interest to several people.

Comment: The two are slightly different, in that _rental_ is also an adjective. The phrase _a rental ad_, with adjectival "rental" immediately sounds more natural to me, but it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Answers and comments so far have given somewhat different opinions. My view is that (1) There's nothing wrong with *ad*; (2) The real difference is in the syntax of *rental* and *shoes*.

**Ad** is a casual use of advertisement, and in that setting is perfectly fine. An ad(vertisement) is a notification that an item or service is available to buy. That seems to be the case here, so I would not use *offer/announcement* here.

If you choose to include a second word, it will function as an adjective. That too is entirely natural: maybe the seller is running multiple ads, and you need to clarify which ad you are interested in.

For that reason, I think rental ad is completely fine. It's an ad for a rental property. On the other hand, I would not say shoes ad (not because a clarifying word is wrong but because that is not the usual expression). I would be more likely to say shoe ad, or perhaps even footwear ad. It's about finding the correct form of the word for use as an adjective.